# Swift instantiateViewController without storyboard ?programming

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

Is there any way instantiateViewController  without using storyboard ? I did not use storyboard.

Comment: Just create an instance of the view controller like you would any other class. What's your actual issue?

Comment: any code example ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: For using storyboard 
storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second")
but I did not using storyboard

Comment: `let viewController = MyViewController()`. What's the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can init you're controller with nib name:

```
let main = UIViewController(nibName: "Second", bundle: nil)
```

Also you can call constructor without parameters like:

```
let main = UIViewController()
```

Comment: thank you! let main = UIViewController() it worked I will accept your answer as correct

Comment: @Kristoff the first line is using from storyboard...basically wherever you see nibName it means *from* storyboard...The 2nd line is purely instantiating a viewController programatically...though you would also have feed the related properties of it ie buttons, labels,views,etc...

Comment: @Honey first approach could be used with nibs also.

Comment: @Honey No, the first one is not using a storyboard. It's using a nib. You can have standalone nibs without ever using a storyboard. Nibs have been around much longer than storyboards.

Comment: @rmaddy ohh ok. Thanks for the correction. But don't you have to create that nib from storyboard? Or your saying you can create nibs programmatically?

Comment: @Honey No, nibs are created in Interface Builder, without using a storyboard. Or when you create a new view controller class, Xcode gives you the option of also creating a nib.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks...after 3000reps you expect to learn more complex stuff rather not knowing the diff between interface builder and storyboard #facepalm!